# Is it possible to preserve items in a Tokio MPSC when the last Sender is dropped, but the Reciever is still active?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a bounded Tokio MPSC queue with one sender and one reciever. I put several items into it in one task (in this case, the numbers 1 to 10, inclusive) and pull those items out in another task. As expected, the receiver processes all 10 values.

Then, I add some other async task in between processing (in this case, by uncommenting the `sleep` call in the receive loop) and now, the contents of the channel are dropped when the last sender is finished.

```rust
use tokio::sync::mpsc;
use tokio::time::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (mut tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(3);
    
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        while let Some(val) = rx.recv().await {
            println!("Recieved {}", val);
            //sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        }
        
        println!("Recieve finished");
    });
    
    for i in 1..=10i32 {
        tx.send(i).await.unwrap();
        println!("Sent {}", i);
    }
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a0cfba02da7aa6851bb675a29c7aa5a9)

Here's the output with the `sleep` commented out (order of interleaved values sometimes changes, but "Recieved 10" is always printed):

```
Sent 1
Recieved 1
Recieved 2
Sent 2
Sent 3
Recieved 3
Recieved 4
Sent 4
Sent 5
Recieved 5
Recieved 6
Sent 6
Sent 7
Recieved 7
Recieved 8
Sent 8
Sent 9
Recieved 9
Recieved 10
Sent 10
```

And here's the output with the `sleep` not commented:

```
Sent 1
Sent 2
Sent 3
Recieved 1
Sent 4
Recieved 2
Sent 5
Recieved 3
Sent 6
Recieved 4
Sent 7
Recieved 5
Sent 8
Recieved 6
Sent 9
Recieved 7
Sent 10
```

Is there any way to be certain that all values put into the queue are processed by the `Reciever` even after the last `Sender` is dropped (assuming that the `Reciever` is not dropped)? The `close` function appears to do this, but going the other way (ensuring that the queue contents are processed before the `Reciever` is dropped). If not, is there an alternate async-friendly MPSC implementation that can provide this guarantee?

Comment: Pretty sure the issue isn't the `Sender` being dropped, it's exiting `main` which shuts down the runtime that is the problem. I believe tokio doesn't wait for idle on shutdown, leaving your receiver uncompleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is that your program exits before the receiver thread finishes. Just make sure you wait for it before exiting:

```rust
use tokio::sync::mpsc;
use tokio::time::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (mut tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(3);
    
    let join_handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
        while let Some(val) = rx.recv().await {
            println!("Received {}", val);
            //sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        }
        
        println!("Receive finished");
    });
    
    for i in 1..=10i32 {
        tx.send(i).await.unwrap();
        println!("Sent {}", i);
    }
    
    std::mem::drop(tx); // Drop the sender so the receiver doesn't listen forever
    join_handle.await.unwrap(); // Wait for the receiver to finish processing
}
```

```
Sent 1
Received 1
Received 2
Sent 2
Sent 3
Sent 4
Sent 5
Received 3
Received 4
Received 5
Sent 6
Sent 7
Sent 8
Received 6
Received 7
Received 8
Sent 9
Sent 10
Received 9
Received 10
Receive finished
```