# Program hangs when using tokio::time::timeout to determine if too much time has passed

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

Consider the following code, with the input being a simple csv file like the one in https://github.com/gophercises/quiz/blob/master/problems.csv:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Problem {
    q: String,
    a: String,
}

impl Problem {
    pub fn new(q: &str, a: &str) -> Problem {
        Self {
            q: q.to_owned(),
            a: a.to_owned(),
        }
    }
}

const FILE_NAME: &str = "../../input/problems.csv";

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let probs = parse_lines().expect("Could not parse CSV file");

    println!("Banana quiz about to start. Press enter when ready.");
    let mut buf = String::new();
    match std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut buf).ok() {
        None => {
            println!("Error reading user input");
            std::process::exit(1)
        }
        _ => {}
    }

    let mut correct_ans = 0;

    for p in &probs {
        println!("What banana? {}", p.q);
        let (banana_s, mut banana_r) = mpsc::channel(512);

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let mut banana = String::new();
            std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut banana);
            banana.pop();
            banana_s.send(banana).await.unwrap();
        });

        let mut banana = String::new();
        match tokio::time::timeout(Duration::from_secs(5), banana_r.recv()).await {
            Ok(opt) => {
                match opt {
                    Some(b) => banana.push_str(&b),
                    None => {},
                }
            },
            Err (_) => {
                println!("Only have 5 seconds to input the answer!");
                return;
            }
        };

        println!("Your Banana: {}, Correct Banana: {}\n", banana, p.a);

        if banana != p.a {
            println!("BAD BANANA!");
            break;
        }

        println!("good banana!");
        println!("------------");
        correct_ans += 1;
    }
    println!("Correct answers: {}/{}\n", correct_ans, probs.len())
}

fn parse_lines() -> Result<Vec<Problem>, csv::Error> {
    let mut builder = ReaderBuilder::new();
    builder.has_headers(false);

    let mut reader = builder.from_path(FILE_NAME)?;
    let mut probs = Vec::new();

    for r in reader.records() {
        let rec = r?;
        probs.push(Problem::new(&rec[0], &rec[1]));
    }

    Ok(probs)
}
```

Everything works fine except in the case in which the user waits for too long (5 seconds) to enter an answer.

After printing the message `Only have 5 seconds to input the answer`, the program does not return unless one hits enter. Once enter is hit, the program panics with the following message:

```
thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: SendError("")', src/main.rs:46:41
```

Line 46 is the line where the string is sent on the channel:

```
banana_s.send(banana).await.unwrap();
```

My understanding is that happens because the thread spawned with tokio is still being blocked by the `read_line()` function. The same thing does not happen if one uses `std::thread` and `std::sync::mpsc::channel`, in fact the program exits happily.

Why is that? And how do I get the program to close once the timeout expired?

I looked at this post (which is fairly similar) but adapting its solution didn't work for me.
[Is it possible to preserve items in a Tokio MPSC when the last Sender is dropped, but the Reciever is still active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65501193/is-it-possible-to-preserve-items-in-a-tokio-mpsc-when-the-last-sender-is-dropped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding seems to be correct. This problem is caused by blocking in an `async` context.

Lets say the question isn't answered in time, the timeout triggers, the user gets a message, and you `return` from `main()`. So the program should exit right?

Well not so fast. Since you're actually returning from an `async` block being executed by a runtime created by `tokio::main`, that runtime needs to shutdown. A standard `tokio` runtime doesn't need to wait for outstanding tasks to *complete*, but it does need them to *yield* execution. The `tokio::spawn`-d block is one of those tasks, but unfortunately, `std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut banana)` is a *blocking* call, meaning it won't yield until it is done (i.e. when you press enter again).

And even when that does complete, it doesn't immediately yield and execution flows to `banana_s.send(banana)`, which returns an error because the receiver, `banana_r`, has already been destroyed and thus the message will never be received. See [Disconnection](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.12.0/tokio/sync/mpsc/index.html#disconnection) in the `tokio::sync::mpsc` docs.

That is why you get the behavior you're seeing.

This machinery can work fine with non-async mechanisms (`std::thread` and `std::sync::mpsc`) because returning from `main()` *does* end the process, meaning other threads are immediately destroyed without requiring their participation.

---

To fix this you should use a *thread* instead of a *task* for accepting user input. You'll probably want to shift from having different channels per question to having one channel that behaves like a stream of input lines. Otherwise you'd attempt to spawn new blocking threads for each one, which could swallow new input from previous timeouts.

```
let (banana_s, mut banana_r) = mpsc::channel(512);
std::thread::spawn(move || loop {
    let mut banana = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut banana).unwrap();
    banana.pop();
    banana_s.blocking_send(banana).unwrap(); // use blocking instead of async to send()
});

for p in &probs { // ...
```

Unless exiting the program on a timeout is the long-term plan, then it wouldn't matter if a previous timeout happened because it would've stopped running anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this is a great alternative to spawning new threads. Unfortunately I am still seeing the blocking upon exit in both of the cases you suggested.

Comment: Oh jeez... the docs for [tokio::io::stdin](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.12.0/tokio/io/fn.stdin.html) says it internally does exactly what I said not to do... That is unfortunate. I guess you should follow their advice there and "spawn a thread dedicated to user input and use blocking IO directly in that thread". I'll modify my answer.

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot! The lesson learnt today is: Always spawn and use a separate OS thread to handle interactive I/O, rather than a green thread.